# `match` arms have incompatible types

Tags: rust, rust-2021

I have some code that needs to create and use a `quick_xml::Writer` with either a `File` or `Cursor` depending on user input. What is the proper Rust way (non-inheritance/no downcasting) to create a `Writer` with different structs but same trait?

All the answers on stack overflow seem to be old and recommend allocating on the heap with Box, but this no longer works, and personally it feels wrong anyway.

Related but outdated now: [How do I overcome match arms with incompatible types for structs implementing same trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378842/how-do-i-overcome-match-arms-with-incompatible-types-for-structs-implementing-sa/32937869#32937869)

**Code:**

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Cursor;
use quick_xml::Writer;

fn main() {
    let some_option = Some("some_file.txt");

    let writer = match &some_option {
        Some(file_name) => {
            Writer::new(File::create(file_name).unwrap())
        },
        _ => {
            Writer::new(Cursor::new(Vec::new()))
        },
    };
}
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src\main.rs:13:13
   |
8  |       let writer = match &some_option {
   |  __________________-
9  | |         Some(file_name) => {
10 | |             Writer::new(File::create(file_name).unwrap())
   | |             --------------------------------------------- this is found to be of type `Writer<File>`
11 | |         },
12 | |         _ => {
13 | |             Writer::new(Cursor::new(Vec::new()))
   | |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `File`, found struct `std::io::Cursor`
14 | |         },
15 | |     };
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `Writer<File>`
            found struct `Writer<std::io::Cursor<Vec<u8>>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Comment: Why do you think it's outdated, except using bare `Trait` (not `dyn Trait`)? The way to do that is still `dyn Trait` or enums.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257469/using-map-as-an-iterator-interchangeably-with-vector-iterator/70257918#70257918

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Using a Box in the related link is what I was referring to. I guess this used to work with older versions.

Comment: @David A box should still work. Alternatively, you could write an enum with a variant for each type, and implement the trait on the enum. This is basically a form of dynamic dispatch, e.g. it does what `dyn` does for you, but does so without requiring a heap allocation.

Comment: Hmm, a box likely won't work here because there isn't a trait that `Writer` implements to use with `dyn`. But the enum approach can still work.

Comment: @Ry This isn't working either. Only difference between that link answer and my code is I'm not declaring the type of writer.

Comment: @cdhowie I've tried the enum way, Box way, and the new way Ry linked and it all results in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `File` and `Cursor` implement `std::io::Write`, so you can solve this by boxing those inner values, giving yourself a `Writer<Box<Write>>`:

```
let writer: Writer<Box<dyn std::io::Write>> = Writer::new(match &some_option {
    Some(file_name) => {
        Box::new(File::create(file_name).unwrap())
    },
    _ => {
        Box::new(Cursor::new(Vec::new()))
   },
});
```

Note that this requires a heap allocation for the `File`/`Cursor` value.  Alternatively, you can use the [`either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.7.0/either/) crate and its primary type `Either` instead:

```
let writer = Writer::new(match &some_option {
    Some(file_name) => {
        Either::Left(File::create(file_name).unwrap())
    },
    _ => {
        Either::Right(Cursor::new(Vec::new()))
    },
});
```

This approach doesn't require any additional heap allocation or indirection.  This works because [`Either` implements `Write` when both the `Left` and `Right` variants do](https://docs.rs/either/1.7.0/either/enum.Either.html#impl-Write).

Comment: can you expand on the enum impl and dynamic dispatch?

Comment: Yes, I am working on an example now.

Comment: @David Added an example. You basically just have to fill in `impl WriterType` with the methods you need from `Writer`, and `writer_type_impl!` handles the dynamic dispatch for you so you don't have to write out the `match` each time.

Comment: @David You might also be interested in the [`either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html) crate. It has [its own macro](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/macro.for_both.html) for dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to make sense but it still feels dirty coming from C++ and or Python. Am I going about this the wrong way completely or do I need to just get used to this?

Comment: @David You'd run into the same thing in C++, and in Python everything is effectively boxed and dynamically typed so that's not exactly a fair comparison.

Comment: @David There's a simpler solution than the above, I'm rewriting my answer.

Comment: This is interesting putting the match inside the `new` call. I'll look at this further when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 2):

The `dyn` thing should be the type parameter to [`Writer`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.23.0/quick_xml/struct.Writer.html). For example, for a boxed trait object,

```rust
let destination: Box<dyn Write> = match &some_option {
    Some(file_name) => {
        Box::new(File::create(file_name).unwrap())
    }
    None => {
        Box::new(Cursor::new(Vec::new()))
    }
};

let writer = Writer::new(destination);
```

`Write` has [the necessary blanket implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-for-Box%3CW%3E) to make the variations on this work.

Comment: @David: Yes, typo, sorry. `Write` here is `std::io::Write`, by the way.

Comment: ```the trait `std::io::Write` is not implemented for `Writer<File>` ```

Comment: @David: Where? Did you keep `Writer::new` in the branch arms accidentally? (It’s replaced with `Box::new`, not wrapped.)

Comment: `Box::new(Writer::new(File::create(file_name).unwrap()))`

Comment: The Cursor arm gives the same error also

Comment: @David: So you kept it in the branch arms accidentally. Again, it’s to be replaced with `Box::new`, not wrapped.

Comment: oh I see what you are saying now, let me try that.

Comment: Okay this works now, the question I have now is if this is a more Rustic way of doing it or @cdhowie answer below

Comment: @David: This is definitely cleaner. Even if you want to use an enum, you should implement `Write` for that and use `Writer<FileOrCursor>`.

Comment: I'm going to switch my answer to this as it does seem cleaner.